# Set rows to TableFooterView

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

So this is my peace of code:

```
        TableView.TableHeaderView = headerLearning;
        TableView.TableFooterView = headerFinished;
```

To *TableHeaderView* rows(fields) setting OK. Anyway I could not set it to *TableFooterView*.

After some research with breakpoints I noticed that after

```
TableView.TableHeaderView = headerLearning;
```

program goes to *override nint RowsInSection...*

**But doesn't go** after

```
    TableView.TableFooterView = headerFinished;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you use

```
 TableView.TableFooterView = headerFinished;
```

I write a simple sample for you and it works for both header and footer:

```
  public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        UITableView table;

        public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            table = new UITableView(View.Bounds); // defaults to Plain style
            string[] tableItems = new string[] { "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Flower Buds", "Legumes", "Bulbs", "Tubers" };
            table.Source = new TableSource(tableItems);
            Add(table);


            UIView headV = new UIView();
            headV.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0,0,100,50);
            headV.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

            UIView footV = new UIView();
            footV.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
            footV.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;

            table.TableHeaderView = headV;
            table.TableFooterView = footV;
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }

    public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
    {

        string[] TableItems;
        string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";

        public TableSource(string[] items)
        {
            TableItems = items;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return TableItems.Length;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
            string item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];

            //---- if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
            if (cell == null)
            { cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier); }

            cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

            return cell;
        }
    }
```

Did you set a frame to `headerFinished`? Share more code about the tablview and we can help you better.

If you want is **section-header** and **section-footer**, you can have a look at this document: [adding-headers-and-footers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/tables/populating-a-table-with-data#adding-headers-and-footers)